# Load ad from audience netwrok with bidPayload

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-audience-network

I use audience netwrok to show ads in my ios app , i need to fix this warning

```
    interstitial = FBInterstitialAd(placementID: "YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID")
    interstitial?.delegate = self
    interstitial?.load() // here in this line
```

> 'load()' is deprecated: This method will be removed in future version. Use -loadAdWithBidPayload

But i don't know what to pass as a parameter to

```
interstitial?.load(loadAdWithBidPayload:"WhatHere")
```

I read this  [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/reference/ios/classes/fbinterstitialad.html/)

> bidPayload
> The payload of the ad bid. You can get your bid id from Facebook bidder endpoint.

Comment: same issue i am facing. Is there any solution?

Comment: Did anyone figure out what we should pass in?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift Show Meta Audience Network Native Ad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77122590/swift-show-meta-audience-network-native-ad)

Comment: Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77181722/1113598)