# Swift Show Meta Audience Network Native Ad

Tags: swift, metaprogramming, ads, facebook-audience-network

I am using Facebook's Audience Network SDK to show a native ad in my app. The question is:

**Where should we get the Bid Payload String to populate the field?**

Code:

```
private func loadFacebookAd() {

    // Remove the previous view before loading a new one
    adView?.removeFromSuperview()

    // Create a native ad request with a unique placement ID (generate your own on the Facebook app settings).
    // Use different ID for each ad placement in your app.
    let ad = FBNativeAd(placementID: "PLACEMENT_ID")

    // Set the delegate of the ad object before loading the ad
    ad.delegate = self

    // TODO: - Initiate a request to load an ad. What goes in the bid payload field?
    ad.loadAd(withBidPayload: <#T##String#>)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/overview/in-house-mediation/server-to-server/ios-setup) you get the bid payload by making a request to an auction server, presumably used for mediation. The response contains the bid payload which can then be used to load an ad.

```
self.payload = json[@"bid_payload"];
```

The documentation in my opinion seems a little outdated though.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you can just use the admob code for both and setup mediation at this url: https://apps.admob.com/v2/mediation/waterfall.

[image]

Comment: I want to use FB's SDK because their ad layout is nicer